# mod_proxy_wstunnel Status line does not end with CRLF

Tags: apache-2.4, websocket

I'm using Apache 2.4.9 with `mod_proxy_wstunnel` and Proxy balancer to load balance between two websocket servers.

I have a Spring Websocket Server to which my client is able to connect without any issues. The moment I add Apache web server with `mod_proxy_wstunnel` , I am seeing intermittent issues. The request doesn't even seem to hit the tomcat and the initial handshake fails.

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Status line does not end with CRLF
```

Any Suggestions on what could be wrong?

```
<Proxy balancer://application-cluster>
    BalancerMember ws://host1.com:20110
    BalancerMember ws://host2.com:20110
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /application/websocket balancer://application-cluster/application/websocket
ProxyPassReverse /application/websocket balancer://application-cluster/application/websocket

<Proxy balancer://application-web-cluster>
    BalancerMember http://host1.com:20110
    BalancerMember http://host2.com:20110
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /application balancer://application-web-cluster/application
ProxyPassReverse /application balancer://application-web-cluster/application
```

Comment: Please add the relevant portions of your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply dawud. What else config would you need?